# How can I create & import a keyspace on Cassandra database 0.7rc2 , on a windows machine?

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa, cassandra-0.7

How can I create & import a keyspace on Cassandra database 0.7rc2 , on a windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in README.txt